# Running processes on different machines causes md5sum incompatibility issue

Tags: ros, md5, shadow-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to run the 'sr_control_gui' on a different machine to the rest of the system and I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] [1311084061.470869449]: Client [/sr_control_gui] wants topic /object_manipulator/object_manipulator_pickup/result to have datatype/md5sum [object_manipulation_msgs/PickupActionResult/37706bf50c1b11b7802944213b641a54], but our version has [object_manipulation_msgs/PickupActionResult/f5b810c9cd81bc41f3d404d9b45717b9]. Dropping connection.
```

From what I understand of it, there is an incompatibility between the messages/topics being published by the different computers, manifesting as an issue with "md5sum"? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10628/running-processes-on-different-machines-causes-md5sum-incompatibility-issue/) by [rohan_k](https://answers.ros.org/users/856/rohan_k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2011-07-19

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you forgot to paste in the actual error. But anyway, the md5sum is a hash of the message and an md5sum mismatch means that the different machines are using different definitions for the same message type. Very likely this is because the message was modified but not compiled on one of the machines.

**EDIT**: What dornhege said, while I was typing mine. :) But still:

Note that this is a pretty common error and is mentioned on the [Troubleshooting](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Troubleshooting) page; please have a good look there next time you run into trouble.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason for different md5sums will be different messages/message definitions. Are you using the same messages/ROS versions on both machines?

- If no, they obviously need to be the same.
- If yes, you should recompile the code and it should result in the same messages.

I have 37706bf50c1b11b7802944213b641a54 on diamondback.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2